# if i disconnect/turnoff my icloud from iphone, does it delete pictures from my icloud? will it delete from my iphone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, graphics

i have synced my icloud to my iphone pictures, if i turn it off will all my photos delete on my icloud? i want to delete a few thousand from my iphone but even if it dosent delete from i cloud can i not delete the pictures from my iphone at anytime/however many myself? will they all stay on icloud photos?

i want to free up storage on my iphone so i want to delete pictures but not to lose them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just disable iCloud Photos, it will not remove them from iCloud, it only disconnects the sync from your phone and the cloud. If you have "Optimize iPhone Storage" enabled, then photos that aren't downloaded will disappear (a warning will appear about this).

If you click Manage Storage in iCloud Photos settings, there is a button to "Turn Off & Delete from iCloud." This will turn it off and delete all data in iCloud in 30 days.